# How do I change this SQL query to work in an MS Access query?

Tags: ms-access

How do I change the following SQL query to Access to make it work?

```
WHERE s.SchoolName like '%' + A.[Choice_School] + '%'
```

I'm trying to look up one column to see if it's contained in another column and this SQL gets me the results I'm after, I just don't know how to concatenate a LIKE operator on a column in Access.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MS Access, the wildcard character is the asterisk (*).

Answer (score 0):

Double quotation marks and asterisk is the Access wildcard. As follows:

```
WHERE [s].[SCHOOLNAME] LIKE "*" & [a].[CHOICE_SCHOOL] & "*";
```